# Quisiera insertar imágenes (que se encuentran en google drive) en mi carousel

Tags: html5, bootstrap, css3, bootstrap-4

Si no es posible, por favor recomienden alguna solución, gracias
Estoy utilizando este código que lo obtuve de la propia pagina de Bootstrap, le realice algunas modificaciones que vi en otra paginas para una mayor adaptación a los diferentes dispositivos. Pero eso no debería de interferir en la imagen, pero lo hace

```
<div id="carouselP" class="carousel slide" data-ride="carousel">
        <ol class="carousel-indicators">
            <li data-target="#carouselP" data-slide-to="0" class="active"></li>
            <li data-target="#carouselP" data-slide-to="1"></li>
            <li data-target="#carouselP" data-slide-to="2"></li>
        </ol>
        <div class="carousel-inner" role="listbox">
            <div class="carousel-item active" style="background-image:url('')"></div>
            <div class="carousel-item" style="background-image:url('')"></div>
            <div class="carousel-item" style="background-image:url('')"></div>
        </div>
        <a href="#carouselP" class="carousel-control-prev" role="button" data-slide="prev">
            <span class="carousel-control-prev-icon" aria-hidden="true"></span>
            <span class="sr-only">Previous</span>
        </a>
        <a href="#carouselP" class="carousel-control-next" role="button" data-slide="next">
            <span class="carousel-control-next-icon" aria-hidden="true"></span>
            <span class="sr-only">Next</span>
        </a>
    </div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Te recomiendo usar un servidor de imágenes en lugar de usar google drive, te evitas líos de compartir carpetas o archivos. También te recomiendo cargar la imagen con la etiqueta `img` de `html` en lugar de usar `background` de `css`.

*Ver snippet en pantalla completa.*

```html
<!doctype html>
<html lang="en">
  <head>
    <!-- Required meta tags -->
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1, shrink-to-fit=no">

    <!-- Bootstrap CSS -->
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.3.1/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-ggOyR0iXCbMQv3Xipma34MD+dH/1fQ784/j6cY/iJTQUOhcWr7x9JvoRxT2MZw1T" crossorigin="anonymous">

    <title>Carousel</title>
  </head>
  <body>
    <div id="carouselExampleControls" class="carousel slide" data-ride="carousel">
      <div class="carousel-inner">
        <div class="carousel-item active">
          <img class="d-block w-100" src="https://i.imgur.com/c3Jyl27.jpg" alt="First slide">
        </div>
        <div class="carousel-item">
          <img class="d-block w-100" src="https://i.imgur.com/abWJAs5.jpg" alt="Second slide">
        </div>
        <div class="carousel-item">
          <img class="d-block w-100" src="https://i.imgur.com/MIkMUbc.jpg" alt="Third slide">
        </div>
      </div>
      <a class="carousel-control-prev" href="#carouselExampleControls" role="button" data-slide="prev">
        <span class="carousel-control-prev-icon" aria-hidden="true"></span>
        <span class="sr-only">Previous</span>
      </a>
      <a class="carousel-control-next" href="#carouselExampleControls" role="button" data-slide="next">
        <span class="carousel-control-next-icon" aria-hidden="true"></span>
        <span class="sr-only">Next</span>
      </a>
    </div>

    <!-- Optional JavaScript -->
    <!-- jQuery first, then Popper.js, then Bootstrap JS -->
    <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.3.1.slim.min.js" integrity="sha384-q8i/X+965DzO0rT7abK41JStQIAqVgRVzpbzo5smXKp4YfRvH+8abtTE1Pi6jizo" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/popper.js/1.14.7/umd/popper.min.js" integrity="sha384-UO2eT0CpHqdSJQ6hJty5KVphtPhzWj9WO1clHTMGa3JDZwrnQq4sF86dIHNDz0W1" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
    <script src="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.3.1/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-JjSmVgyd0p3pXB1rRibZUAYoIIy6OrQ6VrjIEaFf/nJGzIxFDsf4x0xIM+B07jRM" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
  </body>
</html>
```